# How do I prevent Xubuntu 14.04 from turning off when listening to music?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, lock-screen, screensaver

i don't want settings turned to never. I also tried the Caffeine app but couldn't even get it to start, and so here I am.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out [Screensaver Control](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/screensaver-settings/) and see if it will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings.  Battery.  You should see options for when you want computer to sleep, shutoff, ect. I suggest only setting it to never when you are powered via ac. You could write a little shell script to detect when the barttery percentage is below x%, and send the cutoff signal to your music program.  Just a thought.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I have to manually change settings every time I want to listen to music and leave the computer. What I'm try to do tho is some kinds of automation for when, let's say, app X is running, don't ever turn off. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not certain on that one.  You could design a little shell script to do the job. You could have the script launch on startup, and when program with window title x starts up, disable autosleep. just some suggestions.  If you need help with the code, head over to stackoverflow.com